# Making HTTPS request using android volley

Tags: android, ssl, android-volley

I have my cloud vps server on digitalocean and I have implemented letsencrypt ssl certificate to my server. What should I do in android to make secure post/get requests to my server using volley?

Is there any specific things that I should implement? I am very new in this area with ssl certificates, so I have no idea how this really works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS is simply HTTP over SSL

make connection like any standard Request

before  :
   http://www.example.com/user/123

With HTTPS
   https://www.example.com/user/123  //Encrypted by default

Comment: Thank you for the answer, all I needed was someone to tell me that it is safe to make normal requests, as usually.